# Does excess sugar intake cause aggressiveness in children

Tags: eating

Does excess sugar in a child cause aggressiveness?

Comment: This may be better suited on Health.SE.

Comment: Are you asking about short-term or long-term sugar intake? (e.g., is this about the impact of one piece of candy, or about a kid who regularly eats more sugar than recommended?)

Answer (score 3):

Some studies say it doesn't. In fact, it seems the sugar myth is a hard one to beat.  [The meta-analytic synthesis of the studies to date found that sugar does not affect the behavior or cognitive performance of children.](http://jamanetwork.com/journals/jama/article-abstract/391812)

[Busting the Sugar-Hyperactivity Myth](http://www.webmd.com/parenting/features/busting-sugar-hyperactivity-myth#1)

> An analysis of the results of all these studies was published in the
>   November 22, 1995 issue of the Journal of the American Medical
>   Association. The researchers' conclusions? Sugar in the diet did not
>   affect the children's behavior. The authors did point out, though,
>   that the studies didn't rule out completely that sugar might be having
>   a slight effect on a small number of children.
>   ...
>   If after looking at everything else in your child's life you still
>   feel food is causing an adverse reaction, your first step should be to
>   consult with your child's doctor. Extreme approaches, such as
>   eliminating whole groups of foods, can do more harm than good. After
>   giving your child a complete physical and studying his history, your
>   doctor may refer you to a nutritionist or an allergist -- or you might
>   seek one out on your own.

As a teacher, we found that hunger, and thirst could make children more agitated. [Blame serotonin](http://www.scn.ucla.edu/pdf/fairness_freshnews.pdf)